# batch script to check for number of files in folder and then execute command

Tags: batch-file, smtp

I am not a scripting guru nor do I play one in real life.
I am trying to do the following on a Windows 2003 server (yes Win2K3..dont ask..please)

I need to check the number of files in D:\mailqueue
If the # of files is zero then do nothing.

If the # of files is more than 1 then restart the windows SMTP service.
Once the restart is done, check the same folder again to make sure file count is zero.
If not then execute SMTP restart command again.
Keep restarting till queue is zero.

HELP!!!!

I think i got the first part figured out, the count of # of files (yes, may seem trivial but its a HUGE achievement for me)...

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /a count=0
for /F %%N in ('dir "C:\mailqueue" ^| find "File(s)"') do set count=%%N
echo count=%count%
endlocal
```

Now I need to know how to take this value in count and if it is greater than zero then execute a restart of a windows service. After the restart I need to do a count again and see if its zero. if its not then do the restart again and keep doing it till count is zero.

muchos gracias

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you-

```
:do_it_again    
for /f %%i in ('dir c:\mailqueue ^| findstr /i /c:"file(s)"') do set count=%%i  
if "count" neq "1" (    
    net stop smtpsvc & net start smtpsvc
    )
goto :do_it_again
```

Cheers, G